# When focusing at max zoom, focus is lost after zooming out. Is that normal?

Tags: lens, focus, zoom, sigma

On my Canon kit lens, I could completely zoom in, focus on the object and then zoom out to take the picture with the object still in focus.

Now I have a Sigma 18-200mm (with a Canon 600D) and that doesn't work. After zooming out, focus is lost and I need to refocus.

Is this lens broken or is not every lens the same with focussing combined with zooming?

Comment: See also [What is a parfocal lens and how beneficial is it to photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14949/4892) for why you might want a parfocal lens, instead of the varifocal lens that you have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lens is a varifocal lens. Basically, it's a lens that changes focus as the focal length changes and it's quite common. Parfocal lenses, ones that maintain focus on zoom change, exist but are typically more expensive as a result.

Long story short, it's normal for a large number of consumer zoom lenses.

Comment: is 100% correct. Interesting story on lensrental about a 70-200 lens that is Parfocal, its only $20K http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/04/first-look-zeiss-cz-2-70-200mm-t2-9

Comment: Really? I always thought cheap lenses would do that. I've mostly found it on kit lenses, as the asker has stated.

Comment: @BBking - most consumer lenses are cheap lenses...

Comment: The Nikkor 10-105 DX is a parfocal kit zoom, although not exactly one of the pits :)