# How can I quickly tell without testing if my lens is parfocal or varifocal?

Tags: lens, focus

I have read a couple of related questions, but I am curious to find out if there is a list of parfocal/varifocal lenses out there.

I'm most concerned with the lenses I have and I would like to know what they are as well. Considering that [other answers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38266/why-are-so-many-kit-lenses-parfocal-if-its-an-expensive-feature) suggest that the more expensive lenses are more likely to be parfocal, I would like to know about the following lenses:

- Canon 70-200mm f/2.8 L ii
- Canon 24-70mm f/2.8 L ii
- Canon 24-105mm f/4 L
- Sigma 12-24mm f/4.5-5.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a link with parfocal lenses: http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/02/photo-lenses-for-video/4 This list is from February 2011, so if your lens was published after this time it could still be parfocal.

For your lenses:

- Canon 70-200mm f/2.8 L ii  --> No.
- Canon 24-70mm f/2.8 L ii  --> No.
- Canon 24-105mm f/4 L      --> No.
- Sigma 12-24mm f/4.5-5.6  --> No.

Comment: According to a comment by @dpollit the 24-70 is parfocal. He later retracts that statement but it could be that some copies of the lens are almost parfocal. Read his comment here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/what-is-a-parfocal-lens-and-how-beneficial-is-it-to-photography#comment24492_14949

Answer (score 0):

The Canon 70-200mm L II lens is not parfocal. I don't know about the others.

Parfocal means that the focus point stays exactly the same while you zoom the lens, so if you have the ability to see the lens, just focus it, change it to manual focus, then zoom and see if the original focus point is still focused.