# How does focus breathing affect DOF?

Tags: focal-length, field-of-view, f-stop, focus-breathing

Like explained in this question

**[Does focus breathing make a lens slower when close focusing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17454/does-focus-breathing-make-a-lens-slower-when-close-focusing)**

focus breathing does change the effective F-stop. At the same time, the lens behaves, as if it was a shorter focal length.

Since both these factors affect DOF, how can one determine the overall effect on the DOF ?

Comment: I'm not sure I will ever understand the over-awareness about everything that could possibly somehow have an influence on depth of field.

Comment: Some people are just interested in the technical side of photography.  Nothing to wonder about too much :)

Comment: Other times, a question just bugs you, so why not ask it here, where others can potentially profit from it ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question or asking it here at all. =) I was just feeling like we get a lot of questions related to this.

Answer (score 1):

As you close focus you are racking the lens further and further from film/senor. This now elongated distance is no longer called focal length; it is the back focus distance. The focal length is a measurement taken when the lens is imaging an object at infinity (as far as the eye can see).

As you close focus and approach a magnification factor of 1 (life-size often called unity or 1:1), the back focus distance increases one complete focal length. As an example, at unity, a 50mm lens will have a back focus distance of 100mm. The subject to film/sensor distance will be 4× the focal length.

At close focusing distances the depth of field is computed based on the back focus distance. Additionally a revised f-number is plugged into the equation.

At unity the back focus is 2× the focal length, and the f-number is 2 f-stops more stopped down. These revisions must be taken into account when computing depth of field.

Given the following definitions,

> *P* = distance to object
>   *P<sub>d</sub>* = distant point sharply defined
>   *P<sub>n</sub>* = near point sharply defined
>   *D* = diameter of circle of confusion
>   *f* = f-number (revised when close focusing)
>   *F* = focal length (back focus when close focusing)

Then:

> *P<sub>n</sub>* = *P* ÷ (1 + *P∙D∙f/F*²)
>
> *P<sub>d</sub>* = *P* ÷ (1 - *P∙D∙f/F*²)

Comment: @iinkista – I did not intend to delete your edit. It improved my post tremendously. I was looking for a way to accept the edit and I hit the wrong keys. You efforts on my behalf  much appreciated.