# How can a fixed-focus lens have a focus range of 0.5 meters to infinity?

Tags: lens, focus, sensor, optics, photography-basics

I have a Mavic Air 1 drone and I was wondering how the camera of this drone can have a shooting range as large as 0.5 meters to infinity with a fixed focus?

Mavic Air 1 camera specs:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Sensor | 1/2.3” CMOS |
| Effective Pixels | 12 MP |
| Lens FOV | 85° |
| 35 mm Format Equivalent | 24 mm |
| Aperture | f/2.8 |
| Shooting Range | 0.5 m to ∞ |

Comment: See also: [How can a lens with a single focal length focus on more than one plane?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12034/11924)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the camera has a very small sensor (relative to full-frame) and thus a very large depth of field.

A 1/2.3" sensor is 6.17mm×4.55mm, giving a crop factor of 5.64 to full frame. With this, we can plug some numbers into any of the numerous [hyperfocal distance](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-is-hyperfocal-distance) calculators on the web (I used [this one](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/hyperfocal-distance) but it doesn't really matter):

- Sensor size: custom
- Sensor width: 6.17mm
- Sensor height: 4.55mm
- Lens focal length: 4.25mm (calculated as the 24mm equivalent divided by the crop factor, 5.64)

gives us a hyperfocal distance of 1.25m, and a hyperfocal near limit of 0.63m - i.e. if focused at 1.25m, everything from 0.63m to infinity will be in "acceptable" focus. That they come up with 0.5m is just because they have a slightly different definition of "acceptable", but in any case it's not far off.